# Using a CancellationToken for a Task.Run

Tags: c#, task, cancellationtokensource

I have some code that uses `Task.Run` with a cancellation token.

Here is my code:

```
public class TaskObject
{
    CancellationTokenSource _source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public async Task TaskAction()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            await TaskRun();
        }, _source.Token);

        //TaskCancel();

        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    public async Task TaskRun()
    {
        if (_source.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _source.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        SpeechSynthesizer _speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        _speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("This is a test prompt");
    }
    public void TaskCancel()
    {
        _source.Cancel();
    }
}
```

If I call the `TaskCancel()`in the `TaskAction()`, the task cancelled exception is caught.

If I call the `TaskCancel()` from outside the object, the cancelled exception is not caught.

Here is some code to demonstrate where the cancelled exception is not caught:

```
taskObject = new TaskObject();
await taskObject.TaskAction();
taskObject.TaskCancel();
```

How can I call the `TaskCancel()` from outside the object so that the cancelled exception is caught?

Answer (score 5):

Cancellation needs to be cooperative. `Task.Run` has no awareness of what side effects the scheduled delegate might have, therefore the only logically safe point at which `Task.Run` can check your `CancellationToken` and throw an OCE (without leaving your application in a potentially inconsistent state) is *before* the async operation begins - after that point it's up to the user code to check the token.

Trouble is, your user code spends most of its time awaiting `SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync`, which does not have an overload that accepts a `CancellationToken`.

`SpeechSynthesizer` does, however, have a `SpeakAsyncCancelAll` method, which you could plug it in like so:

```
public async Task TaskRun(CancellationToken ct)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    SpeechSynthesizer _speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    using (ct.Register(() => _speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll())) {
        await _speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("This is a test prompt");
    }
}
```

I cannot tell you whether or not this will produce an exception indicating that the operation was cancelled - you'll need to try and see for yourself.

Comment: Disregarding the SpeechSynthesizer, am I correct in saying that when a Task.Run is initiated, there is no way to detect a cancellation request unless at the start of the function?

Comment: @user3736648, you appear have the right idea, but the wording needs some polish (see first paragraph). Put simply, `Task.Run` checks the `CancellationToken` once, at the very beginning, before executing your delegate on the thread pool. Once the delegate invocation is in progress, there's nothing `Task.Run` can do.

Comment: Thank you. Other than Task.Run, is there a correct way to create a thread that can be cancelled at any time?

Comment: @user3736648, this is technically impossible (as it would make it difficult to reason about the state of systems that support cancellation). What you want is cooperative cancellation (i.e. APIs that support cancellation natively, like the `SpeakAsyncCancelAll` call I mentioned earlier). MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can, of course *abandon* your async operation (speech playback in this case), but it's exactly what it sounds like: the synthesizer will keep on playing even though the `Task` is canceled: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx